# iOS: Wait until user finishes typing and then send request

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uisearchbar

I have a simple **UITableView** with **UISearchBar/UISearchDisplayController** that fetches results from remote **ElasticSearch** server by using RKObjectManager. 
Problem I have is that if user types to quickly or the term is a bit bigger several of requests fail and sometimes I don't get the results.

Is there an option to **wait until user has stopped typing** and then send request
instead of sending request per each letter he types in?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Add a small delay before sending the request, and then cancel that delayed request if the user continues typing

```
- (void)searchBar:(UISearchBar *)searchBar textDidChange:(NSString *)searchText
{
    [NSObject cancelPreviousPerformRequestsWithTarget:self];

    [self performSelector:@selector(sendSearchRequest) withObject:searchText afterDelay:0.1f];
}
```

you may need to adjust the delay time. too long and its noticeable to the user that there is a delay, too short and you have the same problem as now

Comment: Any idea how to implement that in swift?

Comment: @Ram I've used the answers suggested here as a workaround for lack of performSelector in swift: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24170282/swift-performselector-withobject-afterdelay

Answer (score 8):

This is for swift version

```
NSObject.cancelPreviousPerformRequestsWithTarget(self)
self.performSelector("searchForText:", withObject: searchString, afterDelay: 0.5)
```