# Fire method periodically at UITextField

Tags: ios, swift, uisearchcontroller

I try to use search controller on my tableview on this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30227166/2924335). If user pause typing on the searchbar for 0.3 sec then it will fire fetch method.

I know how to fire method on every change in search bar using `updateSearchResultsForSearchController`, but it wasn't I want. Then I use search bar delegate `searchBarSearchButtonClicked`, but it fired only when search button on keyboard was pressed.

What I want is fire a method like when user stop typing for 0.3 sec. Is there any way to do this? Or am I going wrong with the concept of using search controller + fetch data?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: This [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9642762/uisearchbar-detect-when-user-stop-type-and-dont-search-immediately-so-detect-pa) or [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24515294/ios-wait-until-user-finishes-typing-and-then-send-request) should help you

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to detect a pause in input for UISearchBar/UITextField?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7061377/how-to-detect-a-pause-in-input-for-uisearchbar-uitextfield)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an `NSTimer` to achieve this functionality.  Simply start or restart the timer in `updateSearchResultsForSearchController`.  Once the user stops typing long enough for the timer to fire, you can perform the search:

```
var searchTimer: NSTimer?

func updateSearchResultsForSearchController(searchController: UISearchController) {

    self.searchTimer?.invalidate()
    self.searchTimer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(0.3,
                                                              target: self,
                                                              selector: #selector(ViewController.searchTimerExpired),
                                                              userInfo: nil,
                                                              repeats: false)
    }
}

@objc func searchTimerExpired() {
    self.searchTimer = nil

    // Do your search
}
```